# Change of variables in integration w.r.t Haar measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Phi:[0,2\pi] \mapsto T$ be such that $\Phi(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$, where $T$ is the unit circle and $\mu \left(S\right)=m(\Phi^{-1}\left(S\right))$ where $S$ is a Borel set of $T$ and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. For a $T$-valued random variable $X$, let $f_X$ be its pdf w.r.t the measure $\mu$, i.e,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X \in S \right)= \int_{S} f_X (t) d\mu(t).
$$
Let $\Theta$ be a $[0,2\pi]$-valued random variable such that $X=\exp(2\pi i \Theta)$. Let $g_\Theta$ be its probability density function w.r.t Lebesgue measure on $[0,2\pi]$. I am trying to prove that:
$$
\int_T f_X(t) \log \frac{1}{f_X(t)} d\mu(t) = \int_{[0,2\pi]} g_\Theta(\theta) \log \frac{1}{g_\Theta(\theta)} dm
$$

Can anyone help me in this? How do I obtain the pdf $g$ from $f$? I am getting stuck at a change of variables formula.